# Не работает код на паскале

Tags: pascal, pascalabc.net

```
var n, c, i, x: integer;
begin 
 readln(n);
 c := 0;
 for i := 1 to n do
    readln(x);
    if ((x >= 100) and (x <= 999) and (x div 100 = 3) and (x mod 5 = 0)) then c := c + 1;
 writeln(c);
end.
```

Он должен находить кол-во трёхзначных чисел, начинающихся на 3 и кратных 5, из последовательности длинной n.

Comment: Если у вас PascalABC.NET, то комбинация клавиш Ctrl+Shift+F (для тех, кто не хочет пользоваться иконкой или меню) отформатирует код и по отступам будет видна логика программы. Если не отформатирует - в программе синтаксические ошибки. Там же можно кликнуть иконку "Здоровье кода" и система оценит, насколько он убог.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Будь проклят тот день, когда [кому-то](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D0%B0%D0%BD_%D0%A0%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%81%D1%83%D0%BC,_%D0%93%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%BE) в башку стукнуло придумать, что было бы хорошо управлять логикой программы при помощи отступов.*

Паскаль не является Питоном. Так что для того, чтобы `readln` и `if` выполнялись вместе, их нужно поместить между `begin` и `end`

```
var n, c, i, x: integer;
begin 
 readln(n);
 c := 0;
 for i := 1 to n do
 begin
    readln(x);
    if ((x >= 100) and (x <= 999) and (x div 100 = 3) and (x mod 5 = 0)) then c := c + 1;
 end;
 writeln(c);
end.
```

Comment: Спасибо, забыл что больше одного действия нужно в begin end засовывать

Comment: Будет лучше всегда засовывать тело цикла или обработку условия в блок. Так меньше шансов огрести глюки при редактировании программы, или при отладке "на скорую руку"

Comment: Зря ругаетесь, отступы - отличная штука

Comment: @Kromster когда есть begin/end или {}. Без них рефакторить (и мержить) чужой код нереально - один неудачно нажатый "пробел" - и начинается цирк там, где его могло и не быть.

Comment: @gbg зато это заставляет следить за форматированием своего кода. А отступы уже давно во всех нормальных IDE делаются автоматически.

Comment: @Alekcvp ага, навязывая форматирование, которое нравится автору языка. Во всех других языках можно отформатировать код при помощи astyle, причем работать можно в своем форматировании, а когда надо - перегонять в корпоративный стандарт, или какой-там-надо стандарт.

Answer (score -1):

### ReadSeqInteger(ReadInteger).Where(x -> (x in (100..999)) and (x div 100 = 3) and x.Divs(5)).Count.Print

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Все это решается в одну строку PascalABC.NET